# ¿Como puedo saber que formulario disparó el submit() desde mi controlador Spring?

Tags: javascript, java, formularios, spring, spring-mvc

Tengo varios modales cada uno con un formulario dentro.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="vasoModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Vasito</h4>
        <h6>Seleccione hasta dos gustos</h6>
        <form id="vasitoForm" method="post">
            <table class="tabla">
                    <tr th:each="gusto : ${gustos}">
                        <td class="flavour" th:text="${gusto.nombre}"></td>
                        <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" th:value="${gusto.id}" name="box"/></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            <p class="errorGustos"></p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar Pedido</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="cucuModal" class="modal">
    <div>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Cucurucho</h4>
            <h6>Seleccione hasta dos gustos</h6>
            <form id="cucuForm" method="post">
                <table class="tabla">
                    <tr th:each="gusto : ${gustos}">
                        <td class="flavour" th:text="${gusto.nombre}"></td>
                        <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" th:value="${gusto.id}" name="box"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p class="errorGustos"></p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar Pedido</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="cuartoModal" class="modal">
    <div>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4 class="modal-title">1/4 Kilo</h4>
            <h6>Seleccione hasta dos gustos</h6>
            <form id="cuartoForm" method="post">
                <table class="tabla">
                    <tr th:each="gusto : ${gustos}">
                        <td class="flavour" th:text="${gusto.nombre}"></td>
                        <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" th:value="${gusto.id}" name="box"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p class="errorGustos"></p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar Pedido</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="medioModal" class="modal">
    <div>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4 class="modal-title">1/2 Kilo</h4>
            <h6>Seleccione hasta tres gustos</h6>
            <form id="medioForm" method="post">
                <table class="tabla">
                    <tr th:each="gusto : ${gustos}">
                        <td class="flavour" th:text="${gusto.nombre}"></td>
                        <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" th:value="${gusto.id}" name="box"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p class="errorGustos"></p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar Pedido</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="kiloModal" class="modal">
    <div>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4 class="modal-title">1 Kilo</h4>
            <h6>Seleccione hasta cuatro gustos</h6>
            <form id="kiloForm" method="post">
                <table class="tabla">
                    <tr th:each="gusto : ${gustos}">
                        <td class="flavour" th:text="${gusto.nombre}"></td>
                        <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" th:value="${gusto.id}" name="box"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p class="errorGustos"></p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar Pedido</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

al hacer el submit() del formulario necesito saber desde el controlador Spring cual de todos los formularios fue el que disparó el submit(). Cada formulario tiene un nombre diferente así que supongo que puedo encontrarlo por ese nombre, pero no sé como se hace.

Alguna idea ?

Intenté con el @RequestParam pero como cada form tiene un nombre diferente no quiero escribirlo mil veces, hay alguna forma más generica de obtener el formulario por ejemplo por el name del mismo ?

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
 <form action="dosomething">
     <input type='submit' name='action' value='action1' />
    <input type='submit' name='action' value='action2' />
 </form>

public class Controller
{
    public String doSomething()
    {
        String action= request.getParameter("action");
        if(action == "action1") 
        {
            dosomething
        }
        else if(action == "action2") 
        {
            do something else
        }
    }
}
```

o puedes hacerlo asi:

```
<input type = "submit" name = "action1" />
<input type = "submit" name = "action2" />

@RequestMapping(params = "action1")
public ModelAndView action1(...) 

@RequestMapping(params = "action2")
public ModelAndView action2(....)
```

o enviando un input type hidden

```
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="soy_elform1">
```

**referencia:**
[mvc multiple form](https://www.javainterviewpoint.com/spring-mvc-multiple-submit-buttons-in-a-single-form/)

Comment: Gracias.! Pero en este caso los forms están todos separados cada uno dentro de un modal, no todos juntos como en el ejemplo.

Comment: Hice algo así pero no le llega al controlador: const allForms = document.querySelectorAll('.formName');     const formNames = new FormData(allForms);    $('#vasitoForm').attr('action', seleccionados + formNames +'/pedido');

Comment: !! Ayudaaaa ... estoy hace 1 hora intentando sin existo !